# how to bypass CodePipeline artifact size limit in CloudFormation AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I have been using AWS pipeline to manage the deployment of my cloud formation stack.
The code pipeline is created using AWS CDK.
I have reached the code pipeline artifact size: 256MB and now I am blocked from deploying new changes.
On Github, they have the following proposed solution :
Add an extra pipeline stage after asset publishing and before application stage deployment, which runs a CodeBuild action to load the cloud assembly, strip out asset files, and generate a new artifact containing only the CFN templates and any data necessary for CFN. The CFN actions should use this new artifact as their input.
It would be great if anyone could help in implementing this solution?

Comment: What's taking up space? Which action is failing?

Comment: @gshpychka it seems not related to file size, it is related to the number of assets generated by the pipeline.When the number of assets generated >38 , it will throw an error related to file size although the file size has not reached its limit

Comment: @Abadi Did you find a solution or a workaround for this?